# Where can I access my index.js file if I deployed to heroku parse from the website

Tags: xcode, heroku, parse-platform

So after parse shut down I started to use a parse heroku datatbase setup and I deployed it for free from the website. I now need to access my index.js file for my app on heroku. How can I do that

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the root directory of the build you committed to heroku.  if you don't know where this is any more you can pull your heroku build to your computer.

These instructions are on the deploy tab of your heroku build.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrrku.png)

Install the Heroku CLI

Download and install the Heroku CLI.

If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the prompts to create a new SSH public key.

```
$ heroku login
```

Clone the repository

In terminal go to the directory you want to clone the build to

```
$ cd your-parse-server-name
```

Use Git to clone parse-server-nextbreath's source code to your local machine.

```
$ heroku git:clone -a your-parse-server-name
$ cd your-parse-server-name
```

your index.js will be in this folder

Deploy your changes

Make some changes to the code you just cloned and deploy them to Heroku using Git.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: is says that when I clone the project its empty

Comment: I don't know then sorry.  when i run $ heroku git:clone -a your-parse-server-name my project is cloned onto my local drive